# How to install xgboost on PythonAnywhere?

Tags: python, installation, python-3.5, xgboost, pythonanywhere

i am trying this :

```
git clone --recursive https://github.com/dmlc/xgboost
cd xgboost
make -j4
cd python-package
python setup.py install
```

but i get the following error:

```
~/xgboost $ python setup.py develop --user
python: can't open file 'setup.py': [Errno 2] No such file or directory
```

how can i install xgboost or something similar(xgb magic,lightgbm ) on PythonAnywhere?

Comment: did you miss this step `cd python-package` ?

Comment: @ hwjp no , i did this step

Comment: i ask because the console listing you pasted suggests you're still in the `~/xgboost` directory, and not in `~/xgboost/python-package` folder as you should be.  that's why it can't find setup.py...