# install xgboost on PythonAnywhere

Tags: python, python-3.x, installation, xgboost, pythonanywhere

Is it possible to install xgboost on PythonAnywhere? I am trying different kind of tutorials but nothing worked .
 i had done   somthing like this:

```
$ make -j4
$ cd ../rabit
$ make lib/librabit_empty.a -j4
$ cd ..
$ cp make/mingw64.mk config.mk
$ make -j4
```

after this i need to build package

```
python setup.py install
```

but there is no \xgboost\python-package in my xgboost folder. What iam doing wrong?
Maybe someone give me step by step guide to xgboost on PythonAnywhere  ?

Comment: Where did you download xgboost from?

Comment: @Giles Thomas pip install xgboost

Comment: That should be all you need to do -- did you get any errors?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to install xgboost on PythonAnywhere?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46800464/how-to-install-xgboost-on-pythonanywhere)

Answer (score 0):

Try using pip install xgboost or conda install xgboost

Comment: There is no conda on PythonAnywhere, and dor pip you need to specify python version (use `pip3.8` or `pip3.7` etc) and provide `--user` flag. Take a look at https://help.pythonanywhere.com/pages/InstallingNewModules/